# Is there a way to use (if number in range) whilst using .apply in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, range

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

| Difference | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.5 | -5 | 5 |
| 7.3 | -3 | 3 |
| 0.1 | -0.1 | 0.1 |

The numbers in the "Min" and "Max" column are different from row to row, but always take the value Min = -Max. What I am wanting to create is a final column that tells me if the value in the "Difference" column falls between the values in the "Min" and "Max" column. Something like this:

| Difference | Min | Max | Signal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.5 | -5 | 5 | Signal |
| 7.3 | -3 | 3 | No Signal |
| 0.1 | -0.1 | 0.1 | Signal |

"Signal and "No Signal" could also be replaced with True or False if there was a way to use boolean operators.

The code that I am currently using is as follows.

```
df['Signal'] = df['Difference'].apply(lambda x: 'Signal' if x in range((df['Min']), (df['Max'])) else 'No Signal')
```

This gives me the error code

```
  File "<ipython-input-52-13b6ff6e946a>", line 5
df['Signal'] = df['Difference'].apply(lambda x: 'Signal' if x in range((df['Min']), (df['Max'])) else 'No Signal')
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried a different approach with the following code

```
df['Signal'] = df['Difference'].apply(lambda x: 'Signal' if df['Min'] <= x <= df['Max'] else 'No Signal')
```

This then gave me the error message

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The issue here is that I don't fully understand the error message and therefore don't know how to go about fixing it.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can try `df['difference'].le(df['max']) & df['difference'].ge(df['min'])`

Comment: @Epsi95 Thank you so much. That's fixed it! I'll add that to my list for future reference.

Comment: You can use apply on complete row of dataframe: `df['Signal'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Signal' if row['Min'] <= row['Difference'] <= row['Max'] else 'No Signal', axis = 1)` (fix of your posted solution).

Comment: @codingnewbie check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix to your posted solution using apply:

```
df['Signal'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Signal' if row['Min'] <= row['Difference'] <= row['Max'] else 'No Signal', axis = 1)
```

- In the above, row is an entire row of DataFrame, allowing row['Min'], etc. to access desired column items.
- axis = 1 means we are using apply on rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution exploiting the fact that the `Min` value is always `- Max`:

```py
df['Signal'] = df.Difference.abs() <= df.Min.abs()
```

This creates a Boolean column that has `True` for those rows where the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pd.Series.between` method for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Difference': [2.5, 7.3, 0.1],
    'Min': [-5, -3, -0.1],
    'Max': [5, 3, 0.1],
    })

print(df['Difference'].between(df['Min'], df['Max']))
```

The output is a boolean Series:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Then we just need to `map` these values to get your desired `'Signal'` column:

```
df['Signal'] = df['Difference'].between(df['Min'], df['Max']).map({True: 'Signal', False: 'No Signal'})

print(df)
```

output:

```
   Difference  Min  Max     Signal
0         2.5 -5.0  5.0     Signal
1         7.3 -3.0  3.0  No Signal
2         0.1 -0.1  0.1     Signal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can give it a try, using [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas-series-between) + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where)

```
df['Signal'] = (
    np.where(df['Difference'].between(df['Min'], df['Max']), 'Signal', 'No Signal')
)
```

---

```
   Difference  Min  Max     Signal
0         2.5 -5.0  5.0     Signal
1         7.3 -3.0  3.0  No Signal
2         0.1 -0.1  0.1     Signal
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the function to the DataFrame if you want to access multiple col/row values (make sure you specify the correct axis):

```
df['Signal'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Signal' if x['Min'] <= x['Difference'] <= x['Max'] else 'No Signal', axis=1)
```

The error refers to the fact that you are comparing one value to a Series (many values). Pandas doesn't know which value in the Series you want to compare `x` to.

Alternatively, you can use numpy's `where` and pandas' `between`:

```
df['Signal'] = np.where(df['Difference'].between(df['Min'], df['Max']), 'Signal', 'No Signal')
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried the .between functon before but couldn't work out exactly how to use it. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `apply` row wise which can be very slow and not preferred way to do, use vectorized approach.

```py
df['Signal'] = (df['Difference'].le(df['Max']) & df['Difference'].ge(df['Min'])).map({
    True: 'Signal',
    False: 'No Signal'
})

print(df)

#    Difference  Min  Max     Signal
# 0         2.5 -5.0  5.0     Signal
# 1         7.3 -3.0  3.0  No Signal
# 2         0.1 -0.1  0.1     Signal
```